# css img background color

Tags: html, css

In the following HTML, I have got a transparent image

```
<img src="transparent.png" class="transparent" />
```

in the style sheet, I used this to make the background color change upon hover

```
.transparent{
    background-color: red;
}

.transparent:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and it's fine, but,, i needed to change the red color for some cases into green, so I used php to to make HTML like this

```
<img src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="background-color: red;" />
```

OR

```
<img src="transparent.png" class="transparent" style="background-color: green;" />
```

in the style sheet, I omitted the first part and left the hover

```
.transparent:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

when I did that, on hover, nothing happens. how to solve that?

Comment: Inline styles over-ride style sheet if they have the same specificity. Try adding "important" to the stylesheet's .transparent:hover

Comment: Instead of changing the style with PHP, change the class.

Comment: [CSS Specificity Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: MathiasaurusRex -  S. Ahn and specially, @showdev thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Inline styles have a higher specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than properties defined in the CSS file.

You can **combine multiple class names** to achieve what you want.

```
.transparent {
    background-color: red;
}
.transparent:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.transparent.green:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

.

```
<img src="transparent.png" class="transparent" />       <!-- blue on hover -->
<img src="transparent.png" class="transparent green" /> <!-- green on hover -->
```

You should **avoid the `!important` rule**, because it makes it harder to overwrite those properties later. For example on a page with an individual style overlay. (e.g. different content types/pages)

**Specificity example**

The selectors could also be written and ordered as follows to achieve that effect:

```
/* same specificity (one class name per selector), order counts */
.transparent:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
.green:hover {
    background-color: green;
}

/* reversed order, but higher specificity due to two class names */
.transparent.green:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
.transparent:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}

/* The base color is always overwritten, even below here, since the
 * additional pseudo-class `:hover` again accounts for a higher
 * specificity of the above selectors. */
.transparent {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: why `.transparent.green:hover` has more priority than `.transparent:hover`

Comment: @Youssef Because of the higher specificity. Follow that link in my answer for an introduction on that CSS behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your inline style has higher priority than rules in style sheet. 
To change this you can use !important keyword

```
.transparent:hover{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

But using inline styles not the best solution and using !important is considered as a bad practice.
It's better to use css classes for this. So your php code will add special css classes, not inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

That should work:

```
.transparent:hover{
background-color: blue !imporant;
```

}